# When draw rect is overridden in iOS, why are translated UIBezierPaths treated differently for sizing a custom UIView?

Tags: ios, uiview, uibezierpath

I override draw rect in a custom UIView class:

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) { ...
```

Then, I draw into it like this:

```
func drawWithGradient(path:UIBezierPath,linearGradient:LinearGradientAttributeSet) {

    let context = self
    context.saveGState()
    path.addClip()
    context.drawLinearGradient(
        linearGradient.gradient,
        start:linearGradient.start,
        end:linearGradient.end,
        options:linearGradient.options
    )
    context.restoreGState()
}
```

And that works great, the UIView fits the size of the UIBezierPath perfectly.
But, I wanted a bit more space above the path, to draw some more things. So, I moved the path down using an affine transform. (This is necessary because there are a lot of images and the amount of space will vary.)

```
let shiftdownAffine = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: roomAbove)
thePath.apply(shiftdownAffine)
```

I didn't change anything else, but the magic was gone. Although I passed the new (translated) path into drawWithGradient, the customUIView matches the size of the original UIBezierPath, while I expected it to behave exactly as though I changed the original UIBezierPath directly through drawing code. With the translated UIBezierPath, the path is drawn at the new location, but the size of the UIView is the same, the so the path gets cut off.

Can you explain why this is happening and/or how to make a translated path that would be treated the same as a drawn path?

Comment: Where in the code are you applying the transform? Would it perhaps be easier to move the view from the view controller? That transform wont make the incoming CGRect any different I would think. (that is, the viewcontroller tells the view what its cgrect is, so when you transform the graphic, its just going to get clipped because it cant change that (my limited understanding)

Comment: Thanks solenoid. These views don't have their own view controllers. I'm not sure how to give them controllers! They are created in code and placed using .addsubview in their parent view's view controller. They pull in the Bezier path from a struct, and if I transform by hand in that struct (actually making the y values higher by 50) it works, but if I transform with affine translate to move by 50 y in that struct, it gets clipped. I noticed only in debug mode, this error appears, "Scrollable content size is ambiguous for UIScrollView".

Comment: The view controller that you use addSubview on will be the parent view controller. From that you can reposition the custom view.

Comment: ex, view.frame = view.frame.offsetBy(dx: CGFloat>, dy: CGFloat)

Comment: Actually, you are right, while it is coming from a struct, it's actually a static function on the struct, so the UIBezierPath IS constructed inside drawrect. So in the case that works, the path has space above it right when it is drawn, but in the case that clips, the path is drawn in the custom UIView, it must get its size at that point from some feature of UIView, then the translation happens.

Comment: Moving the frame from the parent view is having no effect at all. ground1.frame = ground1.frame.offsetBy(dx: 0, dy: -40) Moving the bounds has the same effect/issue as the affine translation. ground1.bounds = ground1.bounds.offsetBy(dx: 0, dy: -20)

Comment: This also had no effect: ground1.frame = CGRect(x: ground1.frame.origin.x, y: ground1.frame.origin.y - 40, width: ground1.frame.width, height: ground1.frame.height + 40.0) Even with         //trying everything!
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        gameScroller.layoutIfNeeded() //actual parent of the views in question
        ground1.layoutIfNeeded()

Comment: is the reference to what you're drawing retained anywhere?

Comment: Yes, there is a path object with a name. To better investigate, I changed the path to a simple circle, and it turns out that the way the UIView is sized to fit the path is just an ultra rudimentary thing. The UIView with this path drawn to it --- let path1Path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x:100,y:100), radius: CGFloat(100), startAngle: CGFloat(0), endAngle:CGFloat(M_PI * 2), clockwise: true) --- is 200x200, nothing cut off. Change y:150, the UIView is still 200x200, and bottom 50 pixels of the circle get cut off. So, u r right, have to size or resize somewhere else...

Comment: I don't think it is UIView itself that is getting sized this way - maybe just the drawing context... or something in between

Comment: Can you add your path + gradient to the views layer? Or pre-calculate the size or offset the view will need before you draw?

Comment: I tried a layer without luck. Pre-calculating should work, but in my test, the constraint I wrote based on pre-calculating was fighting with a constraint that must be added automatically based on intrinsic content size. There's probably a way around that, but I think leave it with the natural content size and respect what it seems determined to do, and then use CALayers to draw additional items, since those do not get clipped. I have that working, except the new additional items are solid instead of gradients. So I'll work on that tomorrow. thx for your help

Comment: (solenoid - if you add answer, I'll arrow up and, if they allow, mark correct)

Comment: CAGradientLayer should help on that, potentially. I was playing with changing the frame inside drawrect, along with affinetransform, and it never works out well (its set for y translate of 50, but it's never actually correct. Changing the frame works, but I don;t have constraints to worry about.

Comment: Yes, changing the frame works. I had a line of code hidden somewhere that was un-doing that. Please add your answer as an answer :-)